# PHP preg_replace first name only

Tags: php

PHP
This is an oversimplification of a problem to get to the point.

I am trying to use preg_replace() on a $string that contains a name. I want to replace an O with an E in the first name only, if there is one. So I want to stop looking when I encounter the first space. There may be multiple spaces in the full name, but I am only looking at the first part of the name.

```
$string = preg_replace('/O/', 'E', $string);
```

How do I add code to tell it to stop at the first space?

Comment: Split the string with `explode()`, perform the replacement on the first element, then put it back together with `implode()`.

Comment: There might be a way to do it in a single `preg_replace()` using a lookbehind, but this will be clearer.

Comment: Yes I was trying to do it with just preg_replace. I use to do that in perl telling it to search up until you hit a space [^/s].

Comment: PHP uses PCRE, so you should be able to do it the same way.

Comment: Just change `$string =~ s/xxx/yyy/` to `$string = preg_replace('/xxx/', 'yyy', $string);` and replace `xxx` and `yyy` with whatever you'd do in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the php.net manual for `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] ) : mixed
```

> **limit**
>   The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

So for your code it would look something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/O/', 'E', $string, 1);
```

[See the documentation for more info - PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: If there's no O in the first name, but one in the last name, this will not do what the poster requests.

Comment: There could be more than one O in the first name, so there is no limit to the number of replaces to make in the first name.

Comment: Why did you accept this answer when it's obviously not correct?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$string = preg_replace('/O[^\s]/', 'E', $string);
```